# Trigger a Function when a button is clicked : woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on a custom woocommerce registration page. is there a way to trigger a function as soon as user click on register button and as soon as that function is executed user will be registered otherwise back to the registration page.

I do not want to use woocommerce_register_post function. its creating a problem when i am fetching data with REST API.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved by running an ajax call at the same time you hit th register button.

However from what i realise here... you could redirect the user to an intermediary php page that runs whatever you are running then redirect the user where he should be going.

ex:

Normal registration flow:

Register page => Registered page

Your flow:

Register page => Your postLogin.php intermediary => Registered page

Should be pretty simple and straightforward

Comment: Yes Exactly. But i am totally new to PHP and ajax. can you please guide me a little bit.

Comment: Simplest method: Go to your registration code and where it redirects you to the thankyou page just modify that line to take you to your postLogin.php like in my example, where you can place your code. Just remember to redirect the user to the thankyou after that is done